# Regularity with respect to the Lebesgue measure through dimensions

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let us consider two probability measures $\mu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{p})$ and $\nu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{q})$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$. We note $\#$ the push forward operator i.e for $f: \mathbb{R}^{p} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}$ measurable $f\#\mu \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{q})$ defined by
$f\#\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\mu(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{p} | f(x) \in A\})$ for $A$ measurable set of $\mathbb{R}^{q}$.

Let $l: \mathbb{R}^{p} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{q}$ be a linear application and assume that $\mu$ has a density $g$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{p}$.

My question is:

If $q <p$ (we go from higher to lower dimension) does $l\#\mu$ has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{q}$ ?

I think this is true using the coarea formula. More precisely if $L\in \mathbb{R}^{q\times p}$ the matrix associated to $l$ and $J_L=\sqrt{det(LL^{T})}$ the density of $l\#\mu$ looks like:
\begin{equation}
h(y)=\int_{l^{-1}(y)} \frac{g(x)}{J_L} dV_{l^{-1}(y)}(x)
\end{equation}
where denotes $dV_{l^{-1}(y)}(x)$ the volume element. Is it correct ?

What could go wrong if $q>p$ (we go from lower to higher dimension) ?

Comment: Your argument is fine but implicitly requires that $l$ is surjective, otherwise $J_L = 0$.  If $l$ is not surjective then it is clear that $l \# \mu$ does not have a density because it gives measure 1 to the image of $l$, which is a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^q$ and therefore has Lebesgue measure zero.  In particular this is the case for every $l$ when $q>p$.

Comment: Building up on Nate Eldredge's comment: in the worst case scenario that your map $l$ is actually trivially zero, you see that $l\|\mu=\delta_{0_{\mathbb R^q}}$ is as far as possible from being absolutely continuous! For the positive answer, one way to put it is that if $\mu\ll dx_p$ then automatically $l\#\mu\ll l\#(dx_p)$. Now if $l$ is surjective it is an easy exercise to check that $l\#(dx_p)\ll dx_q$ (and this is actually an if and only if), hence in particular $l\#\mu\ll l\#(dx_p)\ll dx_q$.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ comment... $$f\#\mu\text{ or }f^\sharp\mu\text{ ??}$$

Comment: Thank you very much !